# forcsvlist to use the expanded result of another forcsvlist

Tags: expansion, etoolbox

My problem is, that I have a list of authors, that I use at several places for several things. For example I would like to generate an Author's index. In the code below I would like to "rework" the text of every author, for example bring the surname forward, put a comma afterwards and then the initials. Finally put these reworked names into an index. I was hoping that I can do it with Latex with `forcsvlist` and expansion.
I have the following sample tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multind}

\makeindex{a}
\makeindex a
\newcommand{\pr}[2]{#1}


\begin{document}



\newcommand{\lastnameelem}{}
\DeclareListParser*{\fordotlist}{.}
\newcommand{\ccgetlastfunc}[1]{\renewcommand{\lastnameelem}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ccgetlast}[1]{\renewcommand{\lastnameelem}{}\fordotlist{\ccgetlastfunc}{#1}\lastnameelem}
\newcommand{\ccgetexceptlastfunc}[1]{\lastnameelem\renewcommand{\lastnameelem}{#1.}}
\newcommand{\ccgetexceptlast}[1]{\renewcommand{\lastnameelem}{}\fordotlist{\ccgetexceptlastfunc}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ccsurnametofront}[1]{\ccgetlast{#1}, \ccgetexceptlast{#1}}

\newcommand{\ccauthorformattedmakefunc}[1]{\ccsurnametofront{#1};}
\newcommand{\ccauthorformattedmake}[1]{\forcsvlist\ccauthorformattedmakefunc{#1}}

\DeclareListParser*{\forsemmicommalist}{;}
\newcommand{\ccauthorlabela}{}
\newcommand{\ccauthormakefunca}[1]{\index{a}{\protect#1|pr{\protect\ref{\ccauthorlabela}}}}
\newcommand{\ccauthormakea}[2]{\renewcommand{\ccauthorlabela}{#1}\forsemmicommalist\ccauthormakefunca{\ccauthorformattedmake{#2}}}

\chapter{XXXXXX}
\label{aaa}
\ccauthormakea{aaa}{A. AAAA, B. BBBBB, C. CCCCC, D. DDDDD, E. EEEE}
Something, something something something something something something 
something something something something something 


\clearpage


\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\input{a.ind}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I would like the `\ccauthormakea` part to expand to the following:

```
\index{AAAA, A.|\ref{aaa}}
\index{BBBB, B.|\ref{aaa}}
\index{CCCC, C.|\ref{aaa}}
\index{BBBB, D.|\ref{aaa}}
\index{EEEE, E.|\ref{aaa}}
```

However I will get in the a.ind file the following:

```
\indexentry{\ccauthorformattedmake {A. AAAA, B. BBBBB, C. CCCCC, D. DDDDD, E. EEEE}|pr{\ref {aaa}}}{1}
```

I was trying to place `\expandafter` into `\ccauthormakea`, but I just could not make it work. Somehow I cannot make one `forcsvlist` to use the expanded result of another `forcsvlist`.
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `etoolbox` syntax, and I don't have `multind` on my system so not so sure about the syntax you want (I don't know what the `|` means here) but anyway, this below will produce this `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{AAAA, A.|pr{\ref{aaa}}}{1}
\indexentry{BBBBB, B.|pr{\ref{aaa}}}{1}
\indexentry{CCCCC, C.|pr{\ref{aaa}}}{1}
\indexentry{DDDDD, D.|pr{\ref{aaa}}}{1}
\indexentry{EEEE, E.|pr{\ref{aaa}}}{1}
```

You may want to replace its `\ccauthorparse` by something more robust, as I don't know if input (initials) may have multiple dots and did not account for that possibility.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\pr}[2]{#1}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\newcommand\ccauthormakea[2]{%
   \xintFor ##1 in {#2}:
   {%
    \begingroup
      \ccauthorparse{##1}%
      \index{\surname, \initials|pr{\string\ref{#1}}}%
    \endgroup
   }%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ccauthorparse[1]{\ccauthor@parse #1\ccauthor@parse}
\def\ccauthor@parse #1. #2\ccauthor@parse
{%
    \def\surname{#2}\def\initials{#1.}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{XXXXXX}
\label{aaa}
\ccauthormakea{aaa}{A. AAAA, B. BBBBB, C. CCCCC, D. DDDDD, E. EEEE}
Something, something something something something something something 
something something something something something 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand now the strange thing with `\pr`... you want to replace page number by using `\ref` macro. The problem is that this was contradictory with that part of the question saying "I would like the `\ccauthormakea` part to expand to the following:", hence I focused on what was asked there ....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you can do it with `etoolbox`, but `expl3` and `xparse` can get you through:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multind}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex{a}
\newcommand{\pr}[2]{#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ccauthormakea}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_ivanyi_authors_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ivanyi_authors_seq
   {
    \__ivanyi_authors_index:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_ivanyi_authors_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ivanyi_authors_index:nn
 {% #1 is the label, #2 is the author
  \index{a}
   {
    #2
    |pr { \exp_not:N \protect \exp_not:N \ref { #1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{XXXXXX}
\label{aaa}
\ccauthormakea{aaa}{AAAA, A.; BBBBB, B.; CCCCC, C.; DDDDD, D.; EEEE, E.}
Something, something something something something something something 
something something something something something 


\clearpage


\setlength{\columnsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\InputIfFileExists{a.ind}{}{\typeout{Remember to run `makeindex a'}}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I warmly suggest you not to rely on an author name format such as `A. AAAA`, because this will be very fragile in case there are more than one initial or a surname is double: it will not be clear at all where to split the entry. A format such as

```
AAAA, A.; BBBB, B.
```

is much clearer and makes parsing much easier.

The version with `imakeidx`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex[name=a,title=Author Index]
\newcommand{\pr}[2]{#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ccauthormakea}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_ivanyi_authors_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ivanyi_authors_seq
   {
    \__ivanyi_authors_index:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_ivanyi_authors_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ivanyi_authors_index:nn
 {% #1 is the label, #2 is the author
  \index[a]
   {
    #2
    |pr { \exp_not:N \protect \exp_not:N \ref { #1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{XXXXXX}
\label{aaa}
\ccauthormakea{aaa}{AAAA, A.; BBBBB, B.; CCCCC, C.; DDDDD, D.; EEEE, E.}
Something, something something something something something something 
something something something something something 

\printindex[a]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the author list is semi column separated then my original implementation would nicely work as well, I just have to remove the \ccauthorformattedmake macro. For example like this: \newcommand{\ccauthormakea}[2]{\renewcommand{\ccauthorlabela}{#1}\forsemmicommalist\ccauthormakefunca{#2}}

Comment: @PeterIvanyi As I said, I can't recommend the `A. AAAA` format.